# Отфильтровать по датам все CSV файлы из одной папки и сохранить отфильтрованные в другую папку

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, обработка-данных

Как сделать, чтобы перебрать файлы из папки `folder_1` в `folder_2`. В `folder_1` есть CSV файлы, в которых по дате от меньшей к большей находятся значения.

Как обрезать лишние даты в файле и оставить только например с 2005.01.01 по 2014.10.01?

Это цель перебора, закинуть во вторую папку обрезанные файлы.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

from pathlib import Path
import shutil

p = Path(r"D:/folder_1")
res = Path(r"D:/folder_2")

for f in p.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: А в чем у вас возникли проблемы? Напишите функцию, которая делает все для одного файла и вызывайте ее в цикле...

Comment: В данной формулировке вопрос больше похож на тех. задание. Именно поэтому я просил уточнить с чем именно у вас возникли затруднения. Вы можете уточнить вопрос? Вы не знаете как парсить даты в CSV или как фильтровать фрейм по датам или как сохранить отфильтрованный фрейм в другую папку?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Тогда разбейте задачу на маленькие блоки и задавайте вопрос по каждому блоку, если возникнет такой вопрос. Это будет  соответствовать правилам ресурса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте функцию, которая будет читать CSV в DataFrame, фильтровать данные по датам и записывать результат в указанную директорию. После этого мы можем воспользоваться `Path.glob("*.csv")`, чтобы обработать этой функцией все файлы в исходной директории:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

src = Path.home() / "Downloads/DropMeFiles_jLSNp"
tgt = Path.home() / "Downloads/DropMeFiles_jLSNp/result"

def do_the_job(file, dt_from, dt_to, tgt_dir=tgt, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, **kwargs)
    df = df.query(f"@dt_from <= index <= @dt_to").dropna(how="all")
    if not df.empty:
        df.to_csv(tgt_dir / file.name)

_ = [do_the_job(f, "2005-01-01", "2014-10-01", 
                index_col=0, parse_dates=True) 
     for f in src.glob("*.csv")]
```